# Ellipse equation. What does it need to be in order for $b > a$?

Tags: quadratics

We have the quadratic equation:

$$ax^2 + bx + cy^2 + dy + e$$
$a$ and $c$ are both negative or both positive.

How can I, by looking at that only, determine whether $b$ (the length of the semi-minor axis) will be bigger than $a$ (the length of the semi major axis)?

Comment: What is the equation? You've given an expression...

Comment: You're using $a$ and $b$ with two different meanings...

Comment: And by the way, the length of the semi-minor axis of an ellipse is *by definition* never greater than the length of the semi-major axis, so you don't even need to look at anything.